# Bash: replace current shell by a new one and refresh groups

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In a term (let's say a PuTTY session), I want to see my current shell bash replacing by a fresh new one, while refreshing the user's groups (among others).

I know that `exec bash --login` replace current shell by a new one, reloading `.bashrc` or `.profile` files, but it does not reloading `/etc/groups`. I suppose this command doesn't load all system configuration file (more details on that will be appreciated).

I know that `su - username` do, but it creates another nested shell, not replacing the current one (and it ask for password). I don't want to type any password, nor have to `exit` one more.

Is there a way to natively achieve this? => Replacing my current shell with a new one, in the exact same way as I log in in another term (s fresh session with reloading bash file, groups, and so.

Comment: This question should be on superuser website. Sorry for the incovenience.

Comment: Asked for it to be closed an a link added to this now, but until the moderation is done, this question has some good answers to this: https://superuser.com/questions/272061/reload-a-linux-users-group-assignments-without-logging-out

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are looking for the `newgrp` command. You don't need to start a new shell, just:

```
newgrp GROUP
```

Of course you need to have added to that group by the system administrator before.

Comment: I still want to get another new fresh shell, in order to load the conf file too. I suppose I could do `exec bash --login` then `newgrp GROUP` but what if there is others envirnnement's file not used with the `exec bash`? I really want the same behaviour as I log in another time.

Comment: You may try `exec sudo login -f YOUR_USER`. Does that work for you?

Comment: Hm. It asks my password for sudo. But it did replace the current shell, and reloading everything. That's close :/ EDIT : I'm not sure the `exec` is usefull, I have the same behaviour without.

Comment: When you don't use `exec` you can type `exit` and will return back to the previous shell. That's why you use `exec`